# How to add tomcat server to eclipse

Tags: java

Adding tomcat server to eclipse, please give me a step by step procedure.
How to use tomcat server in eclipse, How to run the tomcat server with including of java program,

Comment: you should try that first then if you face any problem post on SO :) we will would surely help you.

Comment: google that question, there are so many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

**step1:** download link for tomcat server
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi 
**step2:** Open your eclipse, click on window which is the top in[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtMru.png) your eclipse, click on preferences, right click on server which is left side of the eclipse, click on runtime environment,add your tomcat server which you are downloaded,

Happy and enjy
Thank you,